# Cannot use CommandBehavior.KeyInfo when reading from stored procedure "WITH RESULT SETS"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Run the following in SQL Server 2012 or later

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable1
(
  Dim varchar(500),
  Measure money,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dim)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable2
(
  Dim varchar(500),
  Measure money,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dim)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InnerSp]
(
       @Sql varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC(@sql)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ParentSp]
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @sql = 'SELECT t1.* FROM TestTable1 t1 INNER JOIN TestTable2 t2 ON t1.Dim = t2.Dim'
  EXEC [dbo].[usp_InnerSp] @sql
  WITH RESULT SETS (
   (
    [Dim] VARCHAR(500),
    [Measure] MONEY
   )
  );
END
GO
```

Create a console application in C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_ParentSp", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run the code, you get the following `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` exception:

> EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 2 column(s) for result set number 1, but the statement sent 3 column(s) at run time.

I would expect .Net to run the stored procedure, even if it cannot detect the primary keys for whatever reason.

Question: what would you recommend? It is a bug in .Net or SQL Server?

Comment: From MSDN: The query returns column and primary key information. 
When CommandBehaviour.KeyInfo is used for command execution, the provider will append extra columns to the result set for existing primary key and timestamp columns.  Maybe this is your prob?

Comment: Did you try adding room in the resultset for the primary key based on the keyinfo?

Comment: Just a side note, if you need something as complex as this, reconsider writing as plain C# code.

Comment: accept an answer if it helped you, or the bounty is going to be wasted (you'll still loose it)

Comment: Submitted bug to Microsoft Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1184844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you even using `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` when already selecting the [Dim] column (`t1.*`)?

Either simply not use `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` (best approach).

Or change

```
WITH RESULT SETS (([Dim] VARCHAR(500), [Measure] MONEY));
```

to

```
WITH RESULT SETS (([Dim] VARCHAR(500), [Measure] MONEY, [PrimaryKey] VARCHAR(500)));
```

(worst solution).

Or change `t1.*` to `t1.Measure` and

```
WITH RESULT SETS (([Dim] VARCHAR(500), [Measure] MONEY));
```

to

```
WITH RESULT SETS (([Measure] MONEY, [PrimaryKey] VARCHAR(500)));
```

(better than 2 but still worse than 1).

Comment: "simply not use CommandBehavior.KeyInfo (best approach)"
...
This means that basically .Net code for Sql Client is buggy. You confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: sorry, but I said no such thing - you were simply using it wrong, and I just gave a quick and dirty solution... for more info look at srutzky's answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `WITH RESULT SETS` to begin with? The error has nothing to do with not being able to detect the PK; it has to do with the extra column added to the result set due to specifying `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo`, which in turn sets `SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON` before executing your query. You get the same error in SSMS if you run:

```sql
SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON;
EXEC dbo.usp_ParentSp;
```

Hence the error has nothing to do with .NET either.

There are not too many situations that require `WITH RESULT SETS`, and the example code shown is definitely not one of them, so I would recommend removing the `WITH RESULT SETS` clause from the `EXEC`. And get the result set meta-data from `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()`.

Also, using [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) won't help anyway as it does not support the use of Dynamic SQL. You might be able to get away with [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) as it is ok with Dynamic SQL, but it also requires with `WITH RESULT SETS` clause. Of course, using `WITH RESULT SETS` doesn't do much good in the end as the "is_part_of_unique_key" field is NULL (at least in terms of your test case).